# How to pass a dynamic number of arguments to sed to use as filters

Tags: bash, shell, logging, sed, zsh

I would like to be able to easily search log files.

My log files are very large and look like so . . .

```
-------------------------------
id=<id>
request=<request>
...
status=<status>
metrics=<metrics>
-------------------------------
id=<id>
request=<request>
...
status=<status>
metrics=<metrics>
```

Each log starts with a line of dashes and then there is multiple lines of information that may change for each different log.

So I would like to be able to get output of any logs that match a dynamic number of filters.

I plan to make this a bash function I can call and pass in the `filename` and multiple filters

e.g. Calling it with a single filter

```sh
$ searchLogs <filename> <first-match>
```

e.g. Calling it with multiple filters

```sh
$ searchLogs <filename> <first-match> <second-match> <third-match> ...
```

I found a command that I can use to match with a single filter

```sh
$ sed '/^---/ !{H;$ !d};x;/<search_term>/ !d'
```

...and I could create multiple functions for different lengths and just keep appending `;/<search_term>/ !d` to it for each additional search term but I'd like to build it dynamically if possible and store it in a function so I can easily share it with team members

Here is roughly what I think it would look like . . . but I'm not having any luck

```sh
function searchRequestLogs() {
    logFile="$1"
    searchTerms="${@:2}"
    sedString="'"'/^---/ !{H;$ !d};x';

    for searchTerm in $searchTerms
    do
       # append searchTerm
       sedString=$sedString';/'$searchTerm'/ !d';
    done
    sedString=$sedString"'"

    cat $logFile | sed $sedString;
}
```

I should also note that the log files can be very large so I'm keen not to do too many passes if possible.

Comment: Last line can be simplified to `sed $sedString $filename`

Comment: How should it combine the search terms? Your suggestion will print entries that match *all* search terms (i.e. they're ANDed together), but I suspect you want it to print entries that match *any* of the terms (i.e. they're ORed together).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I do want it to ONLY match if ALL search terms are met i.e. `AND`s ... though I wouldn't mind a solution that would also work for `OR`, however, I got it working for `AND` so that will do for now

Comment: The easiest way I see to combine the filters with OR would be to use extended regex syntax (`sed -E`), and use the `|` operator to OR the filters into a single search term: `sed -E ... /searchTerm1|searchTerm2|searchTerm3/ !d'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution I came up with for `sed`. Happy for others to find possibly better solutions. Especially, if there is any speed enhancements that can be made since some log files may be VERY large

```
# Search a log file with an arbitrary number of search filters
function searchRequestLog() {
    local logFile="$1"
    local filters="${@:2}"
    local sedScript='/^---/ !{H;$ !d};x';

    # loop over filters and add each to sed script
    for filter in $filters
    do
       # append filter
       sedScript=$sedScript';/'$filter'/ !d';
    done;

    # search log file for log events that contain ALL filters
    sed -e "$sedScript" "$logFile";
}
```

Comment: This can have trouble if any filters contain whitespace, or get mistaken for filename wildcards and "expanded" into a list of matching filenames. To avoid this, store the filters in an array and use double-quotes: `local filters=("${@:2}")` and `for filter in "${filters{[@]}"`. Also, I'd use `sedScript+=";/$filter/ !d"` to build the sed script (note: you don't need semicolons at the end of lines in shell scripts).

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep rather than sed to search for text:

```
search_logs() {
    local logfile="$1"
    local searchterms="${@:2}"
    searchterms="${searchterms// /\\|}"
    grep "$searchterms" "$logfile"
}
```

Sample input:

```
$ cat testfile
a
b
c
d
e
```

Sample output:

```
$ search_logs testfile a d e
a
d
e
```

A few remarks:

- use `local` to avoid polluting the global namespace
- use [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to create the search string. For the example above is `a\|d\|e`

Comment: This wouldn't work in my case as I need to first separate logs into single logs which are delimetered by the line of dashes. I fixed my function though so I'll post it as an answer with the use of `local`